# How do I save my game process with RetroPie?

Tags: pi-3, retropie, emulation

I just got a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and have installed NES games. How can I set this up for the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B to save game progress on games that should, such as The Legend of Zelda?  Once I close out of the game all progress is lost.

I only have RetroPie installed so the more details the better for me!